# Image not sliding while creating an image slideshow in html/css/js

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

https://jsfiddle.net/n6buaug5/

I am creating a image slideshow without using any JS library but my image does not slide to next image even though the code seems just fine for me.

Also, I would like to give a slide out effect for the image to be hidden and the slide in effect for the image to be shown. Right now I only wrote

```
@keyframes fade {
            from {
                transform: translateX(100vw)
            } 

            to {
                transform: translateX(0)
            }
}
```

for the slide in part, but I am not sure how to make slide-in and out work together.

Comment: your fiddle works https://jsfiddle.net/6rvb30an/. i just changed load type of your javascript to noWrap in body

Comment: Thanks. But the thing is, when I try to slide to the next one, the current one immediately disappears. Any idea to make it a smooth transition?